# flatmap Lists and Maybes

Tags: haskell

I'm searching for code which can map and flatten Lists and Maybes at the same time. I found such a flatMap-function in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986787/haskell-flatmap):

```
flatMap :: (t -> [a]) -> [t] -> [a]
flatMap _ [] = []
flatMap f (x:xs) = f x ++ flatMap f xs
```

This works fine:

```
> flatMap id [[],[1,2],[3],[],[4,5,6]]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

The only problem is that it doesn't works for Maybes. Instead I have to use `Data.Maybe.mapMaybe`:

```
> Data.Maybe.mapMaybe id [Just 1, Nothing, Just 2, Just 3, Nothing]
[1,2,3]
```

Is there a single built-in function which can handle both Lists and Maybes (and maybe some other types)?

Comment: When you know what you've got you can use [`catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=catMaybes) or [`concat :: [[a]] -> [a]`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=concat) with [`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=map).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think [Data.Foldable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html) may be what you're looking for:

```
> let flatMap f = concatMap (Data.Foldable.toList . f)
> :t flatMap
flatMap :: Data.Foldable.Foldable t => (a -> t b) -> [a] -> [b]
> flatMap id [[],[1,2],[3],[],[4,5,6]]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
> flatMap id [Just 1, Nothing, Just 2, Just 3, Nothing]
[1,2,3]
```

Comment: There's already a function for this in `Data.Foldable` called `foldMap`.

Comment: @dflemstr: What to do to get this to work with Maybe? `foldMap id [Just 1]` produces an error.

Comment: I lied a bit when I said that `foldMap` is identical to `flatMap`: `foldMap` can return *any* appendable type, not just lists. It is the return type of the function that you map that decides which appendable type the outer function returns. The `id` function returns a `Maybe`, so `foldMap` tries to return that. However, `Maybe` isn't a collection of one item like it is in Scala. When you do `mappend (Just [4]) (Just [5])`, it becomes `Just [4, 5]`. If you compare that with lists, `mappend [[4]] [[5]]` becomes `[[4], [5]]`. (To be continued...)

Comment: So, in Haskell, if you append two `Just`s, the second element isn't discarded (Like in Scala); the elements in the `Just`s are appended. Since you can't append `Int`s, your code failed. You need to replace `id` with `toList` if you want a list to be returned instead. You can also create a new `Maybe`-like type that behaves like Scala's `Option` does when appending things. Finally, you can skip using `Maybe`s and just use Lists of one element, which isn't that bad.

Comment: @dflemstr: Thanks for the nice explanation. I think I got it. I changed my code to work with Lists and `=<<` instead of Maybes.

Comment: Perhaps off-topic or I'm missing something but `Some(3) ++ Some(4)` yields `List(3, 4): Iterable[Int]` in Scala — or what did you mean by appending if not `++`?

Comment: @ErikAllik In Haskell, "appending" in this context (in the sense of a Monoid or Semigroup) means any associative operation. For `Maybe`, `mappend (Just (Sum 1)) (Just (Sum 2)) == Just (mappend (Sum 1) (Sum 2)) == Just (Sum 3)`. The operation you gave doesn't typecheck as a possible implementation of `mappend` (the type is `mappend :: Monoid m => m -> m -> m`). Now, note that there are three possible implementations of this that type check and are associative. The other two are provided as `First` and `Last` `newtype`s. `catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]` would be similar to what you're describing.